# Binning data either side of a bin in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, binning

I am trying to bin data by binning it based on the closest bin, rather than what seems to be the standard way in `numpy.digitize` which seems to bin data into the bin above or below the value based on the `right=True/False` argument.

What I have currently implemented is as follows

```
bins = np.array([-100,-90,-80,-70,-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])

np.digitize(imbalance, bins, right=False)
```

Where `imbalance` is a number anywhere between -100 and 100. Currently this method will only bin into the `0` bin when `imbalance` is between -10 and 0.

For example:

```
np.digitize(1, bins, right=False)
```

returns as being binned into the `10` rather than the `0`.

What I would like to happen is that any number between -5 and 5 gets binned into the 0 bin, and so on. Going by the documentation for `numpy.digitize` that doesn't seem to be possible. I have looked into `scipy.stats.binned_statistic` but I cannot see how to do it from reading the documentation there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just do np.digitize(imbalance+5, bins, right=False).

Comment: That is a good and simple solution, surprised I never thought of that! Thanks.